# Get value out of an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, multidimensional-array

I have an array like this:

```
const arr = [1,2,3,4,5]
```

I want to achieve something like this:

```
let answer = 1,2,3,4,5
```

I want the typeof answer to be a number.

Comment: You can get it like that...instead you can get it like this. ..    "1,2,3,4,5" using string concatenation

Answer (score 0):

```
let answer = "1,2,3,4,5"
```

is possible but not what you asked.

```js
const arr = [1,2,3,4,5];
let answer = arr.join(',');
console.log(answer);
```